# JSON RPC: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Request error: Array'

Tags: json-rpc, error, php

I run a small exchange, and we are having a  problem with the DIMECOIN wallet. when sending amounts over 1 million coins. we get the following message when error reporting turned on. I can't for the life of me determine what the error is.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Request error: Array' 
stack trace: #0 ../class.wallet.php(36): jsonRPCClient-     >__call('sendtoaddress', Array)
#1 ../class.wallet.php(36): jsonRPCClient->sendtoaddress('7EFMZkPb6sHhKgk...', 69986000) #2 
../withdrawalqueue.php(128): Wallet->Withdraw('7EFMZkPb6sHhKgk...', '69986000', '1', 'DIME') #3 ../index.php(334): include('..') #4 {main} thrown in ../jsonRPCClient.php on line
```

Here is my code:

```
if ($total > 1000000) {
        return $this->Client->sendtoaddress($address, (double)round($total, 2));
}
elseif($total > 10000000) {
        $amt2s = $total * .1;
        $i = 0;
        do{
            return $this->Client->sendtoaddress($address, round($amt2s));
            $i++
        }
        while($i < 10);

}else{
        return $this->Client->sendtoaddress($address, (double)sprintf("%.8f", $total));
    }
```

Comment: help! i'm having the problem again. i'll update the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, it turns out that the problem lies with the dimecoin wallets in built max money variable, which is capped at 10 million. as you may know, this functionality only affects the maximum size of a transaction, not the actual money supply.